# Traverse array structure with string

Tags: php

Can I store a pre-made array traversal?

I want to store several API calls, and also how I get to the relevant information from their response.

For example:

```
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations='.$location->$latitude.','.$location->$longitude.'&sensor=true';

$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

$result = $response['results'][0]['elevation'];
```

Can I save this part as a string, for storage in my DB or a variable:

```
$elevation = "['results'][0]['elevation']";
```

Then later somehow use it to parse the response, ie.

```
$result = $response[$elevation];
```

Comment: Have you tried doing exactly that?

Comment: LOL no, I just presumed it wouldn't work like that :) will try just now

Comment: Yeah... it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, sorry ! you will need to store your `$response` as it is and call it later on using the correct format `$response['results'][0]['elevation']`

You may however want to use `serialize()` if the problem is about how to persist the array into your database:

```
$db->insert(serialize($reponse));
```

then when you retrieve the response from your db use unserialize:

```
$response=unserialize($db->fetchReponse());
$elevation=$response['results'][0]['elevation'];
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment below it seems what you need is a Cache. Whereby prior to sending the request to the web service API, your application checks in a cache to see if you already have the data available locally. As above example you would most likely want to serialize the PHP array or simply cache the raw response, given that it is in JSON format (PHP serialization will create something very similar anyway).
You would create the Cache key from the query params : location, etc.

Your cached object can be stored in a DB if you choose or on the file system, or even in Memory.

Check out ZF2 Cache component :

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.cache.storage.adapter.html

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is fallback APIs.  Altitude is a bad example, say Weather Forecast.  Based on other logic, once I have reached the usage limit of 1 API I want to start using another to grab the same data.  So I'm looking for an elegant way to store the URL and the means to parse the return data in a db.

Comment: sounds like you need to just implement a cache to store the results locally, see edit above.